# Changing the color of text in a blue button

Tags: html, css

I made a button that brings you back to the top but how would I change the text color? Currently, the output is just a blue button and the text is not visible. Here is my attempt at the code (not working):

```html
<p><strong><a href="#top" style="background-color:#0000FF" class="btn" color="white">Back to Top!</a></strong></p>
```

This is the full code

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <p><strong><a href="#top" style="background-color:#0000FF" class="btn" color="white">Back to Top!</a></strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: So use style `style="background-color:#0000FF; color: #FFFFFF"`

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
 <p>
  <strong>
    <a href="#top" style="background-color:#0000FF;color:white; text-decoration:none;" class="btn">
      Back to Top!
    </a>
  </strong>
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked!! Would you know any way to get rid of the underline below the text?

Comment: edited my code, to remove underline

Comment: Hello it still shows an underline but I marked it as an answer anyway

Answer (score -1):

Whether you are using inline style you must use styling properties in style attribute as follows. `style= "background-color: #0000FF; color: white;"`
**Else it is always an error!**

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make much sense

Comment: As far I know this is the cause behind the error. Styling properties must have into style attribute's quotation mark.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're saying

Comment: I am talking about differences in styling. The code above is an inline style. Check this out https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp